# Python Tkinter cambiar de clases

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo un error al intentar hacer mi código reutilizable, a la hora de abrir y cerrar nuevas pestañas en una prueba con tkinter, el problema es que siempre me reenvía a la misma ventana, lo cual me confunde porque con otros idiomas de programación la misma lógica funciono correctamente.

Modulo donde realizo el cambio de ventana:

```
#Este modulo posee una interfaz y una función que permiten moverse entre ventanas de forma dinamica 
class Index:
    def __init__(self,*args):
        self.ventana = Tk()
        self.aplicaciones = [*args]  #Ventanas a cargar
    def contenido(self):
        print(self.aplicaciones)
        index_row=1
        Label(self.ventana,text="Curso #31").grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
        for x in self.aplicaciones:
            print(x)
            Button(self.ventana,text=x.__name__,comman=lambda:change(window=self.ventana,aplicacion=x)).grid(row=index_row,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
            index_row+=1
        self.ventana.mainloop()
        
def change(window,aplicacion,*args): #recibe por parametro Index y las otras aplicaciones.
        window.destroy()
        if args:
            aplicacion(*args).contenido()
        else:
            aplicacion().contenido()

#El contenido de las apps va en un metodo llamado "contenido"
```

Las aplicaciones no las coloco ya que stackoverflow no me lo permite, pero son simples programas de tkinter con un boton que llama a la funcion change y le pasa por parametro su ventana, la clase index
(destino) y las demas aplicaciones como *args, lo cual segun mi criterio deberia funcionar, ya que el bucle for crea el boton con la clase y deja predeterminado a la funcion cambiar que el parametro que recibira sera una clase, pero me envia a otra aleatoria.  (el nombre de la clase que se muestra en el boton si aparece, pero el parametro no)

La verdad que no entiendo porque sucede esto, desde ya muchas gracias.